# AWS monthly calculator query: is data out counted twice for cloudfront and s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to use cloudfront to stream videos and trying to compute my rough monthly cost.

I had a question regarding the AWS monthly calculator http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

When I calculate the cost of 500GB/day under "Amazon CloudFront" tab, do I need to include that again in "Data transfer Out" under "Amazon S3" tab. If I do that, it is doubling my monthly cost from ~1700$ to 3700$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudFront charges are based on actual usage of the service in three areas: Data Transfer, HTTP/HTTPS Requests, and Invalidation Requests.

For more details please visit: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#What_is_the_price_of_Amazon_CloudFront

[Disclosure : [Bucket Explorer]](http://www.bucketexplorer.com)

Answer (score 0):

The s3 costs remain the same. Cloudfront costs are additional.  Cloudfront does cache content so, depending on the frequency and location of the requests you might not be paying s3 for each request.

This probably belongs in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)